# Defining JQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

The two below functions work as scripted except for when i add the Function next () {;} and function prev () {'} around it to define the custom function.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
function next() {

       $('#up').click(function() {
       $("#two").prev().animate({height:'80%'}, 500);
       });
    ;}


  function prev() {     
       $('#down').click(function() {
       $("#two").next().animate({height:'80%'}, 500);
       });
 ;}
```

Comment: It's a bad habit to mess around with names that are equal to for example jQuery's function names, change your names to something else and try again.

Comment: and beyond @gustav suggestion, you also need to call those function in order to bind the events

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're assigning the `click` event in that function, did you mean to call that function on the click event? Try:

```
$(function () {
   $('#up').click(next); 
   $('#down').click(prev);
});

function next() {
   $("#two").prev().animate({height:'80%'}, 500);
;}

function prev() {     
   $("#two").next().animate({height:'80%'}, 500);
;}
```

Comment: yeah i just came around to it that it the function needs to be called after .click()

Thanks @mattytommo and @martin!

Answer (score 0):

it will work , you can also use prev(), next() after
    `$("#two").animate({height:'80%'}, 500);`

Answer (score -3):

You cant give

```
height:'80%'
```

it should be:

```
height:'80'
```

'%' are not allowed.

Comment: yeah it works with % in there. Is that bad practice to use %?